# vagrant box for ubuntu/xenial64 and putty on Windows 10 host

Tags: ssh, putty, vagrant

I am using vagrant to run some virtual machines on my personal laptop (Windows 10).

I have already installed ubuntu 14.04 and centos on this laptop and all works as expected.

Today I tried to install the new box for ubuntu 16.04 and I simply executed:

```
vagrant init ubuntu/xenial64; vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

After a few seconds the virtual machine was up and vagrant wrote the following message:

> A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
>
> ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
>
> the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
>
> `vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
>
> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>
> ==> default: Box 'ubuntu/xenial64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
>
> default: Box Provider: virtualbox
>
> default: Box Version: >= 0
>
> ==> default: Loading metadata for box 'ubuntu/xenial64'
>
> default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/xenial64
>
> ==> default: Adding box 'ubuntu/xenial64' (v20160420.3.0) for provider: virtualbox
>
> default: Downloading:
>   https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64/versions/20160420.3.0/providers/virtualbox.box
>
> default: Progress: 100% (Rate: 2648k/s, Estimated time remaining:
>   --:--:--)
>
> ==> default: Successfully added box 'ubuntu/xenial64' (v20160420.3.0) for 'virtualbox'!
>
> ==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/xenial64'...
>
> ==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
>
> ==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/xenial64' is up to date...
>
> ==> default: Setting the name of the VM: ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg
>
> ==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
>
> ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
>
> ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
>
> default: Adapter 1: nat
>
> ==> default: Forwarding ports...
>
> default: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
>
> ==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
>
> ==> default: Booting VM...
>
> ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
>
> default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
>
> default: SSH username: ubuntu
>
> default: SSH auth method: password
>
> default:
>
> default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
>
> default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
>
> default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH
>   key...
>
> ==> default: Machine booted and ready!
>
> ==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...

As you can see, because I had already another VM running (that I cannot stop), vagrant used a different port for ssh instead of the default 2222.

When I tried to access the server with putty, I got the following error:

> Disconnected: Server protocol violation: unexpected
>   SSH2_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED packet

I know that I can access the VM using "vagrant ssh". I have already done it, but given that I am on windows, I would prefer to use putty.

**EDIT**
I stopped the other virtual machine and restarted the xenial box that now is using the defaul port, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Try.... Putty config go in Connection->SSH->Kex

Change - Max minutes before rekey to 0 - Max data before rekey to 0

Comment: @Brian - I tried but it did not work.

Comment: To anyone who down voted the question: it would be nice to say why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experience the same problem when I try to access `Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS Server`, clean install with only OpenSSH selected as additional software.  I was using an old 2013 version of PuTTY.

This problem went away when I downloaded and used the ["PuTTY Latest Development Snapshot"](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/x86/putty.exe).